# I want to Redirect a page with get api id onclick button in bootstrap react table2

Tags: reactjs, redirect, datatable, get, react-bootstrap-table

I want to Redirect a page with get api id onclick button in bootstrap react table2

Comment: I am trying to understand your problem here so please correct me if I am wrong. 

You have a set of records in a table with edit buttons and when you click the edit button, it has to pass the id so that you can edit the record that belongs to that particular ID, is that correct?

Comment: I can see your `editRow` function accepts 2 parameters and you are calling that function with an onClick listener. The problem is you are not passing the id as a parameter to that function, eg: onClick={() => this.editRow(id goes here)}. Please let me know if it works. Please change your editRow function into this editRow(Nomovi_LocationId).

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of your output table?

Comment: I have not used the Bootstrap table component so far. But, in general when we map the response from the server, the id's are passed on to the onClick event handler function as a parameter which helps us to identify which record it belongs too. Please check this official documentation of the Bootstrap table. I hope this helps you in some way.
http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/example.html#celledit

Answer (score 0):

Please check this https://material-ui.com/components/tables/. Just map your response from the server as mentioned in the above link. And add this line to your TableCell

`<TableCell align="right"> <button onClick={() => this.editRow(this.state.location.Nomovi_LocationId)}>Edit</button> </TableCell>`

And Please change your editRow function into this `editRow(Nomovi_LocationId)`. Now your are passing the id's of each row to the editRow function which will redirect to the edit page along with the Id. I hope this should work.

Also, You can do this without using any component as well. Look at the below example code.

```
var userid = "8f0d0f73-8d52-468b-9844-16d30d303f57";
var sessionid = "5d90bc03-d7b3-4bbb-974e-e379c52b147a";

class LocationInventory extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            location: [],
        };
    }

render(){
return(
<table className='table'>
   <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>
              //Your table Heading goes here
          </th>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
          { this.state.location.map((data, index) => {
              <tr> 
                    <td><button onClick={() => this.editRow(this.state.location.Nomovi_LocationId)}>Edit</button></td>
             
                    <td>data.LocationName</td>
                    <td>rest of your table data goes here .....</td>
               </tr>
           })}
       </tbody>
   </thead>
</table>
)
}
}
```

Try this and see... Let me know if it works.

Comment: can you help me please add this code to my code i cannot understand where i can add this code